# Laravel: How to handle multiple concurrent function calls on same data by multiple users?

Tags: mysql, laravel, concurrency

We are building a medium scale fintech product on Laravel where users will be able to load money into their wallet, transfer money to any other wallet or settle funds to any bank account using payout APIs.
To add funds, the user is subject to get the approval from the admins for every amount he deposits into his wallet. Once the admin approves, money gets reflected in his wallet.
The issue is, often times, the admin approves the fund request at the same time when the user is transferring money to someone or sending a payout. 
**We have different functions** that get invoked on fund request approval, payout and wallet transfer respectively. These functions are being called concurrently in such instances. This is causing huge issues!

For example, if user A is having $3000 in his wallet and he settles $2000 to someones account but at that exact time, admin approves his fund request of $5000. In this case, the fund request function and payout function both get invoked concurrently. And we get data like this (data is in descending order of timestamp):

| user | tranxn_id | debit_amount | credit_amount | opening_balance | closing_balance | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 140 | PYT123454 | 2000 | 0 | 3000 | 1000 | 2023-04-16 02:00:48 |
| 140 | FND876954 | 0 | 5000 | 3000 | 8000 | 2023-04-16 02:00:48 |

You can see, even if he received funds from admin worth $5000 still his effective wallet balance after payout was just $1000.
I have used DB transactions, locking and what not but I am missing out something. Please help me with your valuable words. 
**EDIT**
I'm attaching my code snippet to better understand what I'm trying to do.

```
DB::transaction(function () use ($amount, $service, $service_type, $user_id, $opening_balance, $transaction_id, $closing_balance, $metadata, $credit) {
        DB::table('transactions')->insert([
            'debit_amount' => $amount,
            'transaction_for' => $service,
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'trigered_by' => $user_id,
            'credit_amount' => $credit,
            'opening_balance' => $opening_balance,
            'closing_balance' => $closing_balance,
            'service_type' => $service_type,
            'metadata' => $metadata,
            'transaction_id' => $transaction_id,
            'created_at' => now(),
            'updated_at' => now()
        ]);

        $user = User::lockForUpdate()->find($user_id);

        $user->update(['wallet' => $closing_balance]);
    }, 2);
```

First, we are adding an entry in the `transactions` table and then we are updating the user's wallet

Comment: Please check out both answers to the duplicate question.

Answer (score -1):

You want to make sure you are using transactions on the controller. Using transactions can help you address the issue of concurrent modifications to the same field in your database. Transactions provide a way to ensure data consistency and integrity when multiple requests are trying to modify the same data concurrently.

You can check this post about transactions in Laravel:
https://laravel.io/articles/using-database-transactions-to-write-safer-laravel-code

Comment: I'm already using `DB::transaction` but still facing this issue. I'm updating my question with my code snippet

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer echoes the common misconception that transactions help with concurrency. No, they are not. Their purpose is to ensure that either all modifications are done or none at all. Concurrency is handled through locks. The reason for the misconception of transactiins handling concurrency is that many database locks are released when a transaction finishes.